# Is there any way to keep playing after a replayed mission in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to replay a mission but keep playing after it. Is that even possible? I searched all over but I can't find an answer. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: No, that's impossible. A mission replay isn't some sort of additional savegame.

Comment: Think of it this way: When you replay a mission you current game is saved. At the conclusion of your mission, your game is loaded at the point before the replay. So, even if you could continue playing the mission, there would be no effect.

Answer (score 4):

You can replay any mission in the game, but doing so will not affect the overall game progression. I believe it's only useful if you're looking to get a better medal score for that particular mission.